# Match all spaces between blocks of characters

Tags: regex, google-cloud-dataprep

I need a regular expression that matchs all whitespaces between block of characters. Block example:

```
500 dfdsfsd     fdsfdsfdsf  9876dfsdfs  df7687
```

I only know about /\s+/ , but it matches only the first whitespace block..
I want to get whitespace, ignore block of characters, get whitespace ... so on
[image]

Comment: Use `/\s+/g`? Global modifier?

Comment: Please tell us which tool or language you are using.

Comment: I'm using google dataprep tryfact

Comment: If you can *match and capture* instead of *splitting*, use `/^(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)$/` for 9 (visible) columns

Comment: For those who get here, you need to set the column number to split, there is no place to set global variables.

Answer (score -1):

If you apply the Regex Flag `global` to your regex expression, you will get all whitespace blocks.

Regex Expression: `\s+/g`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TzbZ7V/2)

Comment: On Dataprep you have to add the tag `global: true` to your transformation and use `\s+` as your regex expression.
[Global-Parameter](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/global-Parameter_57345016?hl=en)